# Can I pull ethernet cable through 1/2" pex?

Tags: pex, ethernet

I have an exterior garage that I need an ethernet cable in for a desktop computer, but it's surrounded by a concrete slab and brick patio (seemingly making it impossible for me to run it underground).

However, someone roughed in two pex pipes from the garage to the basement though -- is it possible for me to use fish tape to pull an ethernet cable through that pex? I know I'd be sacrificing that pex pipe, but having the internet is more important right now

Comment: What about WIFI...there are range extenders.

Comment: You'll want to use cable rated for outdoor underground conduit - not ordinary indoor cable, because that pipe will almost certainly be full of water. Fiber might be worth considering.

Comment: Fiber could go in the AC mains conduit anyway.  Anyway, two "pex" what's up with that?  Potable water plus rainwater for toilet flushing? (mainly: rainwater is not hard water and doesn't leave calcium deposits).  Very small sewer pipe?  Hot/Cold seems like a lost cause, it would take forever and the water would be tepid due to the pipes and concrete sapping the warmth.

Comment: I hope you are talking about pulling bulk cable, *not* cable with connectors on the ends.  Once you get it through, connect to a proper jack - do *not* try to crimp on a connector.

Answer (score 13):

Assuming it's got no fittings with sharp corners, probably.

Use a vacuum cleaner to suck a string (or pulling tape) through, rather than fussing with a fish tape. Don't cut the tube and you **might** even be able to revert it to water use if you change your mind later.

Comment: a ball of fluff on the end of the string can help